# Why can yum still not update GCC 4.9.0?

Tags: linux, fedora, software-installation, yum, gcc

GCC 4.9.0 has been released since April 22. However, I can still not update it through the following command:

```
$yum update gcc
```

Why does the yum repository lag so much behind gcc.gnu.org?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fedora is going switch to new GCC version when their core packages are compiled with it. The current plan as I see is to switch GCC in Fedora 21 to 4.9.x and rebuild all packages with it. So you will have to wait until Fedora 21, which is currently planned for last quarter of 2014.

More info: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/GCC49
https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Releases/21/Schedule

Comment: If you _really_ don't want to wait, consider switching to [Rawhide](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Releases/Rawhide), Fedora's continuous development release. It's not _quite_ for the faint of heart, as sometimes things break, but that's the price of following the latest versions of things. (Disclaimer: I'm a Fedora developer. Also, more on Rawhide in the middle of [this blog post](http://fedoramagazine.org/five-things-in-fedora-this-week-2014-04-15/) I wrote.)

Comment: I have a couple of questions regarding your answer:
1) why does Fedora 21 need to build all packages with gcc 4.9 in order to include gcc 4.9 as its system compiler?  Are binaries built with gcc 4.8 not compatible with binaries build with gcc 4.9?  In what ways?

The second question is: I upgraded from Fedora 20 to Fedora 21, `cat /etc/fedora-release 
Fedora release 21 (Twenty One)`.   But gcc is still 4.8. If I do `sudo yum update gcc` Then I get:
`Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
No packages marked for update.`
Whats up with that? Did Fedora 21 not build with GCC 4.9 in the end?

Comment: @orm: 1) It's a path chosen by Fedora team, I don't know the reasons behind it. 2) This was anwered 6-7months ago and it was the current plan, which might have changed during this time. You can investigate maybe there is more information in the links provided.